# c# automapper - Latitude, Longitude to Point converter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to map a ViewModel to a model. I am new to Automapper and I find the documentation incomplete. After hours of search, stackoverflow seems to be the last stop.
This is what I am trying to map:
**ViewModel**

```
public class UpdatedCompleteLocation
    {
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
        public string? Address { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string? Region { get; set; }
        public string? Country { get; set; }
    }
```

To:
**Model**

```
public class EventLocation
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? EntityName { get; set; }

        public string? City { get; set; }

        public string? Region { get; set; }

        public string? Address { get; set; }

        public string? Country { get; set; }

        public string? CountryCode { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "geometry (point)")]
        public Point Location { get; set; }
    }
```

The trick comes when I try to map Longitude, Latitude to X, Y in the `Location` of type Point which is part of `NetTopologySuite.Geometries`. Also as a precondition, the lat/long has to be not null.
This is what I came up with so far:

```
 CreateMap<UpdatedCompleteLocation, EventLocation>()
             .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```

Comment: Have you considered mapping manually? It is a very simple model.

Comment: @Crowcoder trying to avoid that as much as possible. Less code - less things to maintain

Comment: That is a valid opinion but I personally don't like the "magic" of automapper and the maps can get quite complicated, negating  the usefulness, in my opinion. Maintainable code is also readable code. What is easier to read, that CreateMap statement or simply setting something equal to something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with Automapper, you must add a custom conversion for the `Location` property. Using your existing CreateMap, you can extend it like:

```cs
CreateMap<UpdatedCompleteLocation, EventLocation>()
   .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Point(src.Longitude, src.Latitude));
```

Comment: I don't see how the CtorParams can help here. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: If the `Point` constructor parameters are named X and Y, it's probably not worth it unless it's used in other places too.